# Permission is null error for ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION permission 'n React Native

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, permissions, activity-recognition

I try to ger permission from React Native app via PermissionsAndroid.

It's my request:

```
await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION, some other permissions which work well])
```

When I try to run this I get the belowing screen:
[image: permission is null]

I tried to remove other permissions and the error screen come from this permission.

I added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />` and also `<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />` to androidManifest.xml.

My react native version is 0.67.

What is your idea?

Comment: Have u try`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`?

Comment: Yes I already use them too without problem.

Answer (score 0):

i just want to inform those who are using `WRITE_SMS` permission that there is a specific bug with this and you also don't actually need it to send SMSs using the `react-native-get-sms-android` package, the `SEND_SMS` is enough for that.